# DC/DC converter, from 36V to 32V

Tags: voltage-regulator, switching-regulator, linear-regulator

I have to do a DC DC conversion from 36V to 32V @1.5A. I found some switching regulators, but no linear regulators. 
I'm not sure using a switching regulator is the best solution (price, overkill, efficiency) to reduce voltage.

What would you advise?

Comment: Linear will be 88% efficient (32/36) and dissipate 6 watts. Since your 32V load uses 48W it most likely has a heatsink and a fan already, so getting rid of 6 extra watts should be easy. Switching DC-DC could be 90-95% efficiency, saving a few watts... not really worth it... Now, to suggest a regulator is impossible without knowing what the load is, notably its PSRR and regulation needs.

Comment: DC-DC usually implies some form of input-output isolation - is this what you are looking for? If not call it a regulator.

Comment: DC-DC does not imply isolation (Buck is a DC-DC for example). Still, without knowing the load's needs, can't reply...

Comment: load will be an audio power amplifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a standard 3 pin adjustable linear regulator. You can use those at much higher voltages since they do not directly use a ground reference.

Limiting factor is Delta Vin-Vout.

e.g.
[image]

Comment: Upvoting this, since the other answers are... hmmm, LOL... and this is the only one which will work. I'm still waiting for the OP to confess that his load is a motor or something like that, though...

Answer (score 0):

A simple NPN-zener regulator would do the job. Adjust you zener voltage accordingly. You can stack several zener diodes in series to make 32+~0.7 V in total. Choose a NPN which can handle more than your maximum input voltage plus margin, more than your maximum current and can dissipate (36-32)*1.5 W.
[image]

Comment: NPN not PNP! Also add an op amp for better regulation.

Comment: @dirac16 Sorry. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about an op-amp voltage follower: -

[image]

Plenty of op-amps will run above 36 volts so this shouldn't be a problem. I might be tempted to add output current limiting as well if the 36 volt supply is capable of many amps. The NPN transistor need to be a power transistor of course and requires a heatsink for the volt drop (4 volts) x 1.5 amps of max power.